# Show and hide form element based on values of other form elements

Tags: javascript

`$form['bookpage']` should be hidden at first. Then should be shown based on user selected value in `$form['student']`.

But somehow, before user selects anything, upon loading the option list, it already triggers the `$form['student']`'s ajax function and shows the `$form['bookpage']`.

Why is this so?

P.S. `_lms_user_get_students` will return following array:

> array('0'=>'----', 'all'=>'All', '2456'=>'Student A', '2462'=>'Student
>   B')

```
 $form['student'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Student'),
        '#options' => (!isset($form_state['values']['book']) || $form_state['values']['book']==NULL)?array('0'=>'----'):_lms_user_get_students($form_state['values']['class']),
        '#prefix' => "<div id='student_div'>",
        '#suffix' => "</div>",
        '#id' => 'select-student',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_student_select_callback',
            'event' => 'change',
            'wrapper' => 'statistic_table_div',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade'
       ),
   );


  $form['bookpage_toggle'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => 'off'
  );     
$form['bookpage'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => t('Page'),
            '#options' => (!isset($form_state['values']['book']) || $form_state['values']['book']==NULL)?array('0'=>'----'):_lms_user_get_bookpages($form_state['values']['book']),
            '#prefix' => "<div id='bookpage_div'>",
            '#suffix' => "</div>",
            //'#disabled' => TRUE,

            '#states' => array(
                'visible' => array(
                    ':input[name="bookpage_toggle"]' => array('value' => 'on'),
                ),
                'invisible' => array(
                    ':input[name="bookpage_toggle"]' => array('value' => 'off'),
                ),
            )
       );


    function ajax_student_select_callback($form, &$form_state) {

        //show page drop 
        if($form['student']['#value'] == 'all') $form['bookpage_toggle']['#value'] = "on";
}
```

Comment: Your ajax callback should either pass `$form` by reference (`&$form`) or you should use `$form_state`. As of now, nothing you do there affects the form. Also as far as I know there is no need to define both the visible and the invisible state. If it is visible when the value is `on`, it is invisible in all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Why the in-between form element? You can use [Drupal's Form API #states property](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/conditional-form-fields) to check for a value in a select as well. Just check the `student` form element and it's value `all`.

```
$form['bookpage'] = array(
  ...
  
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="student"]' => array('value' => 'all'),
      // Use multiple lines here for an AND condition. eg:
      // ':input[name="other-field"]' => array('value' => 'all'),
    ),
  )
);
```

This way you can remove the AJAX callback, and the `bookpage_toggle` element.

If you want to support multiple conditions, you can wrap the jQuery selectors in another array  to function as an OR:

```
$form['bookpage'] = array(
  ...
  
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      array(':input[name="student"]' => array('value' => 'all')),
      array(':input[name="student"]' => array('value' => 'other value')),
    ),
  )
);
```

Finally if you want exclusive OR (XOR) you can do it like this to toggle on one of the elements, but never both of them:

```
$form['bookpage'] = array(
  ...
  
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      'xor',
      array(':input[name="student"]' => array('value' => 'all')),
      array(':input[name="student"]' => array('value' => 'other value')),
    ),
  )
);
```

See [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/51758#comment-51758) for AND, OR and XOR and a combination of those.

Comment: because there will be one more condition on other field value, which I don't know how to set: $form_state['values']['book'] != 'all' . So I get around this using the in-between element.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more examples.

Comment: Thanks. but the 'other value' are dynamic data loaded from database...